# Unable to find NodeEntity or related Entities

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Dears,

I've created a very simple application with Spring Boot (1.5.7.RELEASE) and Spring data neo4j (4.2.7.RELEASE) and neo4j-ogm (2.1.5).

Relevant parts of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-test</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have two simple entities and one parent (with common stuff):

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Convert(value = InstantConverter.class)
    private Instant createdOn;

    private Date modifiedOn;
}

public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Index(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Index(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    public User() {
        //default
    }

    public User(String username, String email, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}

public class Tag extends BaseEntity {
    @Index
    private String label;

    @Relationship(type = "CREATOR")
    private User creator;

    public Tag() {}

    public Tag(String label, User creator) {
        this.label = label;
        this.creator = creator;
    } 
}
```

I removed setters/getters/equals/hashcode for clarity.

Using this configuration for Neo4j, trying to be as simple as possible:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(value = "xxx.repository")
public class Neo4jConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public NewEntityPreSaveEventListener newEntityPreSaveEventListener() {
        return new NewEntityPreSaveEventListener();
    }
}
```

Here is the repository I use:

```
@Repository
public interface TagRepository extends GraphRepository<Tag> {
    Tag findOneByLabelAndCreator(String label, User creator);

    Tag findOneByLabel(String label);

    Tag findOneByCreator(User creator);

    @Query("MATCH (tag:Tag)-[:CREATOR]->(creator:User) WHERE id(creator) = {creatorId} RETURN tag")
    @Depth(value = 5)
    Tag getByCreator(@Param("creatorId") User creator);
}
```

So nothing fancy, really...

Assuming that:

```
User myCreator = userRepository.save(new User("myCreator", "email", "password"));
Tag myTag = tagRepository.save(new Tag("taglabel", myCreator));
```

When I do "tagRepository.findOneByLabel("taglabel")" or , it returns the tag with all properties set. Perfect!

When I do "tagRepository.findOneByCreator(myCreator)", it simply returns null.

When I do "tagRepository.getByCreator(myCreator)", it returns the tag with the right label BUT the property "creator" is null.

I really don't get it. Of course, I read the documentation and I tried several things (@Depth, the custom @Query, adding @Relationship in the User class on a field "Set tags", removing indexes, etc). It simply doesn't want to work properly. 
It's so simple that I should miss something very, very stupid...
Unfortunately, all the examples that I found are even simpler than this one... which isn't very helpful.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> When I do "tagRepository.findOneByCreator(myCreator)", it simply returns null.

Turn on info logging for `org.neo4j.ogm` and check the generated cypher query for this.

> When I do "tagRepository.getByCreator(myCreator)", it returns the tag with the right label BUT the property "creator" is null.

See [this part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference_programming_model_annotatedQueries) of the documentation:

> Custom queries do not support a custom depth. Additionally, @Query does not support mapping a path to domain entities, as such, a path should not be returned from a Cypher query. Instead, return nodes and relationships to have them mapped to domain entities.

So you need to return all nodes/relationships you want to map, plus you need to handle the depth in the query yourself.

```
@Query("MATCH (tag:Tag)-[:CREATOR]->(creator:User) " +
       "WHERE id(creator) = {creatorId} WITH tag " +
       "MATCH p=(tag)-[*..5]-() " +
       "RETURN nodes(p),relationships(p)")
@Depth(value = 5)
Tag getByCreator(@Param("creatorId") User creator);
```